# Fullname parsing on specific fname, mname, lname

Tags: sql, sql-server

Identify and parse the multiple fullname of customer.
Example:

```
select * from tb1_customer

FullName(column name)
Timothy Theodore Duncan
Michael Scott James Jordan
Steve Henry Francis Johnson Jr.
Alvin John Brooks Alva Sr.
Bryan Nash Job Jr.
... and more
```

expected output

```
Lname  |  Mname  |  Fname
Duncan Theodore Timothy
Jordan James Michael Scott
Johnson Francis Steve Henry Jr.
Alva Brooks Alvin John Sr.
Job Nash Bryan Jr.
```

How can transfer all the names in tb1 with 1 fields only to tb2 with fields on Lname, Mname, Fname respectively?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I understand the question you're asking. You may need to format the output a little more. But I'm really not able to figure out your request.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected output result, my friend?

Comment: specify your database please, Ex.MS SQL,ORACLE,MYSQL,Postgres

Comment: Parsing names into parts is an impossible task since names are not structured. You might encounter names like Madona where there's only one name,or  names like Pablo Picasso - his full name was Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso.

Comment: Must read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Ms sql database

Comment: Fullname in tb1 are complete with fname mname and lname some with suffix. The problem is how can i transfer it to tb2. Other fname and lname somtimes have a two words.

Comment: A common question that has been repeatedly discussed on the web - both here and elsewhere. Try searching before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to define the rules on how the names are entered, maybe you could try and parse them. But it seems impossible.
How can you say what is the Fname and the Mname for Johnson Francis Steve Henry Jr?
Is Mname Francis Steve and Fname Henry Jr or Mname is Francis and Fname Steve Henry Jr ?